# Is there a way to post the images on google+ wall using my ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I have checked the API but it allows to post the URL not the image?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read on the internet the Google+ API (https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/) currently does not allow for an upload like that.

Instead some people have been using the Picasa Web SDK (https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) since it is what powers Google+'s images.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to write to a user's Stream in any form. However, you can make this feature request in our Issue Tracker, which you can find at https://developers.google.com/+/support.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Google+ History was deprecated on February 26, 2013

Checkout the [Google+ History developer preview](https://developers.google.com/+/history/learn-more).

The History API allows you to record different [types (docs)](https://developers.google.com/+/history/api/moments) of user interactions.

For now these interactions only show up in the History tab (along with all other Google activities for that account). From there the user is able to share to it's timeline.

This is a developer preview, and it's probably not a good idea to go live with an app that uses this. But it gives you the opportunity to start developing for the future. I can imagine a user has a future option to autopost certain types of history to it's timeline.